# undefined method `match' for 1:Fixnum when using link_to [RoR]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= link_to "Edit Review", controller: "reviews", action: "edit", id: review, host: @host.id %> 

Controller Code:

def edit
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    @host = Host.find(params[:host])
end
```

For some reason "host: @host.id" in my link_to caused the error in the title to appear. I'm not sure why. I'm trying to push the host ID to the edit page for reviews as its required. I'm not sure if its something to do with the variable type but, I'm sure its something silly I'm overlooking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option `host` in `link_to` method sets host that would be linked to. You should rather pass `host_id` param:

```
<%= link_to "Edit Review", controller: "reviews", action: "edit", id: review, host_id: @host.id %>
```

and find use it in controller:

```
@host = Host.find(params[:host_id])
```